# Longest sorted subarray that contains a given element

Tags: arrays, recursion, data-structures

I applied recently to a Front-End Dev job and one of the test questions was to write a function that takes in an array of integers and an integer `0 <= n < arr.length` and returns the longest sorted subarray that contains `array[n]`. And the function has to be recursive.

Example:

```
array = [3, 1, 4, 7, 9, -3]
function(array, 0) => [3]

function(array, 1) => [1,4,7,9]

function(array, 2) => [1,4,7,9]

function(array, 3) => [1,4,7,9]

function(array, 4) => [1,4,7,9]

function(array, 5) => [-3]
```

I had 30 minutes and couldn't come up with an answer.

Comment: That seems like recursion just for the sake of recursion. Anyways, if you’re given a sorted array and an integer `x`, can you test whether appending `x` to the end of the array keeps it sorted?

Comment: @kcsquared The problem didn't state that the array is sorted and if it were that would mean that the function will always return the whole array since it is the longest sorted subarray containing any element.
Yeah I didn't understand why it was to be done recursively...

Comment: Yes, that was just a suggestion for how to solve it recursively. A single element subarray is sorted by definition. Try extending such a list one element at a time, using some fast way to test if the list would remain sorted. Once you know how to do that, you have the subproblem structure to solve the full problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was my first ever real job test and I was so stressed that I couldn't see it!!!!

Thanks @kcsquared for the idea, I just needed the spark to ignite the idea!

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Solution {
    public static int[] longestSortedSubArray(int[] arr, int pos) {
        int left = checkLeft(arr, pos);
        int right = checkRight(arr, pos);
        int[] result = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, left, right + 1);
        return result;
    }

    public static int checkLeft(int[] arr, int pos) {
        int left = pos;
        if (pos - 1 >= 0 && arr[pos - 1] < arr[pos]) {
            left = pos - 1;
        }
        if (left == pos)
            return left;
        return checkLeft(arr, left);
    }

    public static int checkRight(int[] arr, int pos) {
        int right = pos;
        if (pos + 1 < arr.length && arr[pos + 1] > arr[pos]) {
            right = pos + 1;
        }
        if (right == pos)
            return right;
        return checkRight(arr, right);
    }

}
```